# Trouble getting Vimeo filename from API using PyVimeo

Tags: python-3.x, vimeo-api, pyvimeo

I have an script using Python and PyVimeo that I am working on to use the "GEThttps://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}" so I can get the file name. When I try to run my app, I am getting an error `{'error': "The requested video couldn't be found."}`. However, when I use this same video ID under the `Try it out` section (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video), it works fine.

I am assuming there is something wrong with my code, but if I use the demo from the [github example](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py#:%7E:text=pip%20install%20PyVimeo-,Usage,-import%20vimeo%0A%0Av) `(about_me = v.get('/me'))`, it works fine and that needs authentication as well.

Is there something simple I am missing? Thank you so much.

```
import vimeo

v = vimeo.VimeoClient(
token= 'VimeoToken',
key= 'VimeoKey',
secret= 'VimeoSecret'
)

class Vimeo:
def get_vimeo_data(video_file):
uri = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_file}'
# uri = 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos' - This response works
response = v.get(uri)

data = response.json()
print(data)

Vimeo.get_vimeo_data(55555)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add an `f` before your f-string.

```py
class Vimeo:
    def get_vimeo_data(video_file):
        # THIS f
        uri = f"https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_file}"
        # uri = 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos' - This response works
        response = v.get(uri)

        data = response.json()
        print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment.  I think I entered " instead of ' .  It should look like this.

     `uri = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_file}'`

Comment: @user3324136 if my answer solved your question please click on the check mark to accept my answer :)

Comment: Thank you Siddharth.  I certainly will give you an up vote.  Right now, however, the issue is that I am not trying to use an F string but use the URI to get the JSON from the video file.  I corrected the code above to reflect what I was trying to do and (my apologies) somehow quotes got placed in it accidentally.

Comment: My apologies, Siddharth.  I had not fully read through your answer and it was indeed correct.  Thanks again for your help.